# Covariance of a random variable and a converging random variable.

Tags: probability, covariance

If I have $\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}X_n=X$. ($X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$). Does $\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}$Cov$(X_n,X)$=Var$(X)$?

To me it should, if I am allowed to pass the limit into the covariance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if the distribution of $X_n$ is exactly the distribution of $X$, this need not be true. Consider $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $X_n =-X$.